# is it the Board's approval or Board approval?

Tags: grammar

I've seen both have been used in many articles and documents. The only difference I can see is that if 'the' is added before 'Board', they usually use apostrophe + s. Does the apostrophe for possessives no longer apply if 'the' is not added before 'Board'?

Answer (score 1):

With the article, "the board" is a **noun**, and as such, needs to be made into a possessive in order to properly convey the grammar.

Without the article, just "Board", it is no longer a noun... it is an **adjective**!  Most nouns can be used as adjectives in this manner.  As an adjective, of course it would not have an "apostrophe s" as the grammar is entirely different.

Distinguishing between a noun form and an adjective form of a word is one of the major uses of articles.

> the Board's approval

The approval comes from someone-- namely, the Board.

> board approval

This is approval.  What kind of approval is it?  It's not red approval or fast approval, it's board approval.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation.